# Comparing multiple columns in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to compare two different columns in a mysql `WHERE` statement. Within a view that I have created I have a column called `E_ID` and one called `event`. I need to `SELECT` from the view where the `E_ID` != `$E_ID` when `event` = `$event`.

So if `$event` = status and `$E_ID` = 1 the statement would select anything thats not got the same event and the same `E_ID` but it could return data that has the same `E_ID` and a different event.

Okay lets have some examples. Lets say I have this as my two variable:

```
$E_ID = '1';
$event = 'status';
```

Okay and now in the table is this;

```
E_ID    event

1       status
2       status
3       status
1       gig
3       track
5       gig
```

As you cans the first row contains the data set in the variables so we don't want to return that. But the problem lies in `E_ID` as they can be the same if the event is different. So I want to return everything that does not have the `E_ID` of `1` when the `event` is `status`. It can however return data of the same E_ID and the same event.

What should be returned is this;

```
E_ID    event

2       status
3       status
1       gig
3       track
5       gig
```

As you can see everything is returned but the row that has the data set in the variables.

Here's my query so far.

```
SELECT * FROM stream_view WHERE E_ID != '$E_ID'
```

Not really sure where to start so have struggled to figure it out myself

Comment: can you please make a sqlfiddle of your tables? www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: do you want to select what is != $E_ID and = $status? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @fabio no I want to select what is not `$E_ID` WHEN event = `$event`. So if there are a few events such as gig, track and status it will return data that does not have the same E_ID for rows that have the same event

Comment: is event a list comma separated?

Comment: No its not it can be any value

Comment: @nbs189 I have updated my query. Only WHEN event = '$event', does the filter `E_ID <> '$E_ID'` get applied because of the `OR` I have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the OP is more interested in this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
stream_view 
WHERE (event = '$event' 
AND E_ID <> '$E_ID') 
OR  event<> '$event';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
SELECT * FROM stream_view WHERE E_ID != '$E_ID' AND event = '$event'
```

Comment: $event should be surrounded with quotes since it's not integer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just place both condition in your `WHERE` clauses

```
SELECT * FROM stream_view WHERE E_ID != '$E_ID' and event = '$event'
```

Comment: No actually I don't mean this. Ignore my previous comment that i've now deleted. This will select event only = to '$event'. Look at my example to see what i'm after

Comment: @nbs i took a look at your example but i didn't figure out what you are trying to achieve, could you please explain?